# C# SQL: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagrid

I'm new to SQL in C# (and SQL in general).

I'm making this simple users management program (which is  part of a bigger thing), where you have the option to register a new account, and view all the SQL Data Base content in a DataGrid.

I can add users, (Read/write from the DB) but for some reason, when I load the WPF page with the DataGrid, it crashed when it tries to load it and gives the error:

`Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.`

I tried to google an answer, but I couldn't find one, or understand what should I do.

this is my C# code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    //SQL
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    namespace FMS_Csharp_GUI
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UsersBD.xaml
    /// </summary>
   public partial class UsersBD : Window
   {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        string sqlConnectionString;
        public UsersBD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FMS_Csharp_GUI.Properties.Settings.UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FMS_Csharp_GUI.UsersDataSet usersDataSet = ((FMS_Csharp_GUI.UsersDataSet)(this.FindResource("usersDataSet")));
        // Load data into the table UsersTable. You can modify this code as needed.
        FMS_Csharp_GUI.UsersDataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableTableAdapter usersDataSetUsersTableTableAdapter = new FMS_Csharp_GUI.UsersDataSetTableAdapters.UsersTableTableAdapter();
  /*code crash in this line: */      usersDataSetUsersTableTableAdapter.Fill(usersDataSet.UsersTable); 
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource usersTableViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("usersTableViewSource")));
        usersTableViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "INSERT INTO UsersTable VALUES (@username, @password, @IsAdmin);";

        //get input
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        bool admin = chckAdmin.IsChecked == true;

        using(connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection)) {

            connection.Open();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAdmin", admin);

            command.ExecuteScalar();
        }

    }
}
}
```

this is my SQL DB code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersTable] (
[Id]          INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]        NCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
[PasswordMD5] NCHAR (32) NOT NULL,
[IsAdmin]     BIT        DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

this is my data base:
[image]

Thanks a lot!
P.S. `FMS_Csharp_GUI` is the name of the program.

Comment: What is FMS_Csharp_GUI? That looks like some third party tool of some sort. Also, you really should NOT store passwords in plain text, they should be salted and hashed. I would also recommend defining the datatype and size of your parameters instead of AddWithValue. It can sometimes cause performance issues or even get things wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Sea edit, Yes I know you don't save password as plain, this is just a test. I'll see about addWithValue. Anything about the problem itself?

Comment: Well this is usually caused by getting either a NULL or a duplicate value in your resultset in a column you defined as the primary key of the datatable. Googling your error message a little over 20,000 hits. The first several all mention the same that I just did.

Comment: Also, I hope you don't plan on using MD5 as your encryption method. It is really old and has been broken for quite some time.

Comment: I don;t think it returns any nulls...

Comment: Don't guess. Run the query in sql server and check it out. Does it return NULL or any duplicates?

Comment: any query I run works. I have a problem with the built in data grid thing. All MY scripts are working OK, but the data grid (which i drag -drop) doesn't work, I don't know what script to run.

Comment: It isn't that the query won't run. It is because you are either getting duplicate values or NULL in the column(s) that you have specified as the primary key for the data table. What is the primary key column as defined in your datatable? There is still the unknown question about FMS_Csharp_GUI. What is that?

Comment: FMS_Csharp_GUI is the GUI of the program FMS I'm making. its all my code. in the whole thing there are only 2 function that deals with SQL. the one above is one, and the second one is almost the same. but there is only one data grid. If I don't use the data grid - every thing works OK).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89845/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-789).

Comment: Based on the data you displayed, do either the Name or PasswordMD5 columns have unique constraints on them?

Comment: both are not nulls, and are nchars type. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't konw it didn't work. but now it does, after I tried to do this :

```
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID,Name,PasswordSHA256, IsAdmin"
            + " From UsersTable", connection))
        {
            //get data
            DataTable user = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(user);
            usersTableDataGrid.DataContext = user;
        }
```

then I highlighted this code, and used the one above, and it worked!

maybe getting it this why made it work?